AlarmManager.AlarmClockinfo.getNextAlarmClock() How to detect alarm source
I  need to find out not only the time of the next alarm, but also what set it.
The problem is that the function
AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo info = ((AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE)).getNextAlarmClock();
long alarmTime = info.getTriggerTime();

returns me the time of the next alarm, even if no alarm is visible on the phone alarm page and this time comes from, for example, the Calendar application settings.
The system knows how to find out that it is not an alarm clock application, but another application like Calendar.
I should like to detect it too.
Any advice? "https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager" does not help me.
